# Implementing the visitor pattern using C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates, visitor-pattern

I've been trying to reduce the amount of boilerplate in my code, by using C++ Templates to implement the visitor pattern. So far I've come up with this:

```
class BaseVisitor {
public:
    virtual ~BaseVisitor() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Visitor : public BaseVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(T& /* visitable */) = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
class Visitable {
public:
    void accept(Visitor<Derived>& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
    }
};
```

And each subclass of Visitable looks like this:

```
class Mesh : public Object, public Visitable<Mesh> {};
class Text : public Object, public Visitable<Text> {};
```

And finally the Visitor looks like this:

```
class Renderer : public Visitor<Mesh>, public Visitor<Text> {}
```

So far so good... now here's the problem:

```
for(Scene::iterator it = scene.begin(); it != scene.end(); ++it) {
    Object& object = static_cast<Object&>(*it);
    if(pre_visit(object)) {
        object.accept(this); ///Erm, what do I cast to??
        post_visit(object);
    }
}
```

I need to somehow cast to Visitable so that I can call accept(), but obviously I don't know what T is. Alternatively I can't add a virtual accept() to the Visitable template, because I don't know what argument it should take.

Any C++ Templating guru's out there know how to make this work?

Comment: Here is the currently modern way to do it: [visiting-without-travelling](https://backwardsincompatibilities.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/visiting-without-travelling/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be done in C++11 using variadic templates.  Continuing from Pete's answer:

```
// Visitor template declaration
template<typename... Types>
class Visitor;

// specialization for single type    
template<typename T>
class Visitor<T> {
public:
    virtual void visit(T & visitable) = 0;
};

// specialization for multiple types
template<typename T, typename... Types>
class Visitor<T, Types...> : public Visitor<Types...> {
public:
    // promote the function(s) from the base class
    using Visitor<Types...>::visit;

    virtual void visit(T & visitable) = 0;
};

template<typename... Types>
class Visitable {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor<Types...>& visitor) = 0;
};

template<typename Derived, typename... Types>
class VisitableImpl : public Visitable<Types...> {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor<Types...>& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
    }
};
```

Subclasses of `Visitable`:

```
class Mesh : public Object, public VisitableImpl<Mesh, Mesh, Text> {};
class Text : public Object, public VisitableImpl<Text, Mesh, Text> {};
```

A `Visitor` subclass:

```
class Renderer : public Visitor<Mesh, Text> {};
```

It's not clear what the `value_type` of your `Scene` container is but you need to obtain a reference or pointer to `Visitable<Mesh, Text>` on which to call `accept`:

```
for(Scene::iterator it = scene.begin(); it != scene.end(); ++it) {
    Visitable<Mesh, Text>& object = static_cast<Visitable<Mesh, Text>&>(*it);
    if(pre_visit(object)) {
        object.accept(*this);
        post_visit(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this only works if accepted `Visitor` supports all the classes specified in the `VisitableImpl` specialization in the exact same order, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Your BaseVisitor does nothing for you, other than allowing arbitrary visitees to delete the visitor. Instead, you want to have a base class for the visitor which provides *all* of the different `accept` functions that could be called on it, and for the `Visitable` to accept this visitor.

To do this, you could use a [type list](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&lpg=PA52&vq=type%20list&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false) to define the types the visitor can accept, have a base visitee class which takes the type list, and add the type list as a parameter to your visitee implementation.

sketch of example:

```
// assuming a typelist has typedefs first and second and a 
// type 'empty' representing end of type list

template<typename Types>
class Visitor : public Visitor<Types::second> {
public:
    // visitor has a visit function for each type in Types
    virtual void visit(typename Types::first& visitable) = 0;
};

template<> class Visitor<empty> { };

template<typename Types>
class Visitable{
    public:
    // base accepts a visitor which can visit any type in Types
    virtual void accept(Visitor<Types>& visitor) = 0;
};

template<typename Derived, typename Types>
class VisitableImpl : public Visitable<Types> {
public:
    // impl calls specific visit function 
    virtual void accept(Visitor<Types>& visitor) override {
        visitor.visit(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also in need of a templated Visitor pattern, and was able to create a solution that does not involve the usage of variadic types or type lists.

```
// forward declarations for our Visitable interface
class Object;
class Visitor;

// Visitable objects can accept a visitor.
class Visitable
{
public:
    virtual ~Visitable() { }
    virtual void accept_visitor(Visitor& visitor) = 0;
    virtual void accept(Object& obj);
};

// A base class, to allow downcasting
class Object
{
protected:
    virtual void _f() { }
};

// Our Visitor class, which will wrap our concrete visitor implementation
class Visitor
{
public:
    Visitor(Object* obj);

    // Base class for concrete visitors
    template<typename D, typename V>
    class OfType : public Object
    {
    public:
        void visit(V* visitable) {
            D* derived = static_cast<D*>(this);

            // "duck-typed" method; if our derived class does not have
            // this method, compilation will fail.
            derived->on_visit(visitable);
        }
    };

    template<typename D, typename V>
    void visit(V* visitable);

private:
    Object* m_obj;
};

Visitor::Visitor(Object* obj) : m_obj(obj) { }

template<typename D, typename V>
void Visitor::visit(V* visitable) {
    // check if our visitor is able to visit this instance
    OfType<D,V>* visitor = dynamic_cast<OfType<D,V>* >(m_obj);
    if (visitor) {
        visitor->visit(visitable);
    }
}

void Visitable::accept(Object& visitor) {
    Visitor wrapped(&visitor);
    accept_visitor(wrapped);
}
```

After the above interfaces are defined, create specific interfaces for a visitable object's visitor, then implement them in your concrete class:

```
class This;

class ThisVisitor : public Visitor::OfType<ThisVisitor, This>
{
public:
    virtual void on_visit(This* item) = 0;
};

class This : public Visitable
{
public:
    void accept_visitor(Visitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visit<ThisVisitor>(this);
    }
};

class That;

class ThatVisitor : public Visitor::OfType<ThatVisitor, That>
{
public:
    virtual void on_visit(That* item) = 0;
};

class That : public Visitable
{
public:
    void accept_visitor(Visitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visit<ThatVisitor>(this);
    }
};

class MyVisitor : public ThisVisitor, public ThatVisitor
{
public:
    void on_visit(This* item) { printf("This!"); }
    void on_visit(That* item) { printf("That!"); }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[] {
    This item1;
    That item2;
    MyVisitor visitor;
    item1.accept(visitor);   // "This!"
    item2.accept(visitor);   // "That!"
}
```

You could also skip the visitor interfaces entirely and have your concrete visitor derive from `OfType<Derived, SomeClass>` directly, but I find using the former is better for extending your visitor as new classes are defined (`That` should not care about who visits it as long as it is of type `ThatVisitor`).