# design for separated visualization from code of polymorph classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have some class hierarchy that is mainly a data model. eg:

```
class A; ///< abstract base class
class B: public A;
class C: public A;
class D: public A{
  QList<QSharedPointer<A>> m_a;
}
```

Now I want to write code to visualize a `List<QSharedPointer<A>>`. Visualization of the classes requires to distinguish of their real type.
Obviously i do not want to add dependencies from my data to the visualization code.

Is there an elegant way to do so without conditionals based on dynamic casts?

Comment: Have you looked at the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

Comment: @TartanLlama yes I looked over it. But as far as I understood it, the visitor base class has to know all descendants of `A`. Also the implementation of each descendants `accept`-method has to know the visitor base class, because otherwise the compiler could not chose the correct `visit`-overload. In my Opinion it is also not that elegant, because it adds a lot of boiler plate code and some sort of circular dependency.

Comment: There are ways to inject the names of the derived classes into the base class, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796121/implementing-the-visitor-pattern-using-c-templates). But you're right; it can lead to a fair amount of boilerplate. But that's design patterns for you ;)