# C++: Overriding virtual pure function derived from a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, variadic-templates

I wrote some classes based on this excellent visitor pattern described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796121/implementing-the-visitor-pattern-using-c-templates) (my implementation is a little bit different).

```
template<typename... Types>
class Visitable {
public:
     virtual void accept(Visitor<Types...>& visitor) = 0;
};

class MyClass : public Visitable<int, string>
{
     virtual void accept(Visitor<int, string>& visitor)
     {
          /*** my code ***/
     }
};
```

This code above works but I would like implement `MyClass` like that:

```
class MyClass : public Visitable<int, string>
{
      template<typename... Types>
      virtual void accept(Visitor<Types...>& visitor)
      {
              /*** my code ***/
      }
};
```

Obviously I changed the call to the accept method but I have this error: "*cannot instantiate abstract class*". Why in this second case, `accept()` is not overridden ? MyClass should be templated ?

Thanks.

Comment: A template is not a function, so there is no function to override the base class function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CRTP:

```
template<class D, class...Ts>
struct Visitable_CRTP : public Visitable<Ts...> {
  virtual void accept(Visitor<Ts...>& visitor) override final {
    return static_cast<D*>(this)->accept_impl(visitor);
  }
};
class MyClass : public Visitable_CRTP<MyClass, int, string>
{
  template<typename... Types>
  void accept_impl(Visitor<Types...>& visitor) // not virtual
  {
          /*** my code ***/
  }
};
```

`Visitor_CRTP` writes the glue code that attaches `virtual accept` to your `template accept_impl`.

If you want to have more than one `accept` method, we can do this:

```
template<class D, class...Visitables>
struct PolyVisitable_CRTP {};

template<class D, class...V0, class...Vs>
struct PolyVisitable_CRTP<D, Visitable<V0...>, Vs...>
  Visitable_CRTP<D, V0...>,
  PolyVisitable_CRTP<D, Vs...>
{};
```

which can be used like this:

```
class MyClass :
  public PolyVisitable_CRTP<MyClass,
    Visitable<int,double>,
    Visitable<std::string, char, wchar_t>,
    Visitable<>
  >
{
  template<typename... Types>
  void accept_impl(Visitor<Types...>& visitor)
  {
          /*** my code ***/
  }
};
```

and all of the `Visitable` bases's `accept`s will be routed to `accept_impl`.

Code not tested or compiled, probably contains tpyos.

Comment: At least the word "tpyos" contains a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact you try to implement

```
void VisitTable<int, string>::accept(Visitor<int, string>& visitor);
```

with

```
void MyClass::accept<int, string>(Visitor<int, string>& visitor);
```

In C++ it is not the same method name - one has a template qualification and the other not. Moreover `template` and `virtual` are incompatible specifiers for methods and you should have an error for

```
class MyClass : ... {
  ...
  template<typename... Types>
  virtual void accept(Visitor<Types...>& visitor);
};

error: templates may not be ‘virtual’
```

The `override` C++11 keyword helps to avoid such surprises.

Comment: With your remark I understand now my mistake. Thank you. Usually I use `override` but here I forgot it.